# Multiply and division without operators in C 4byte float ieee754

Tags: c, math, floating-point, bit-manipulation, ieee-754

I need some help doing programing.
I have to write a program, which can divide and multiply without the opearators and contains the IEEE 754 standard. I can use only +,-, negation and logical operations. The numbers and the operators needs to be read from a file.

I got this so far, but it's not working correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

float mult(float a, float b) {
    float i = 0;
    float c = 0;
    while (i < b) {
        c = c + a;
        i++;
    }
    return c;
}


//this will be needed to divide
float product=1,multiplier=2,a=1;
int steps=0;
void divCore(float number, float divideBy,float lastDivison)
{
    steps++;
    if(number - divideBy < 
        return;
    else
    {
        lastDivison = divideBy;
        divideBy *= multiplier;
        if(number >= divideBy)
        {
            product *= multiplier;
            divCore(number,divideBy,lastDivison);
        }
        else
        {
            a *= 0.5;
            multiplier = 1 + a;
            divCore(number,lastDivison,lastDivison);
        }
    }
}
//its an other function for division ,you use this in main
float Divide(float numerator, float denominator)
{
    //init data
    int neg=(numerator<0)?-1:1;
    neg*=(denominator<0)?-1:1;
    product = 1;
    multiplier = 2;
    a = 1;
    steps =0;
    divCore(abs(numerator),abs(denominator),0);
    return product*neg;
}

int main()
{
    float i,j;
    char c[2];
    FILE *in=fopen("input.txt","r");
    fscanf(in,"%f",&i);
    fscanf(in,"%s",c);
    fscanf(in,"%f",&j);
    if(strcmp(c,"*")==0){
        float a = mult(i,j);
        printf("%f\n", a);
    }
    if(strcmp(c,"/")==0){
        float a2 = Divide(i,j);
        printf("%f\n", a2);
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

And the file looks like this (I think the numbers doesnt count):

```
0x0000C942
*
0x0000C942
```

Comment: What is stopping you from debugging your code ?

Comment: I admit I didn't read anything else but at least you're reading an hexadecimal number (0x...) with as float (%f)

Comment: Yeah, I know about that, I tried my options, to see the results, and just copied the last version, which was wrong.

Comment: There is _a lot_ yet to go. First: read and print the float.  Then the `mult()`.  The `while()` loop will not cut it. `float` does not necessarily always have whole number values that your loop depends on.

Comment: I see several `*` operators in your code. 
What about calls to `log`/`pow`?

Comment: What is **if(number - divideBy <** ?

Comment: I suggest building this up logically, adding and testing one thing at a time. Start by getting your floats read and written. Next work on multiplication, which is simpler than division. Do some long multiplication in decimal on paper and pencil, to get the principles of doing the operation in mind. Use numbers in scientific notation. Think and read about IEEE rounding. Begin with either doing a multiplication without rounding, or on rounding arbitrary results, then combine them. At each stage, test and, if necessary, debug until you are sure that piece works correctly.

Comment: if(number - divideBy < 0.01)

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun (so do not downvote please). This code abides rules presented in the task ;-) ie. does not use C division(/) or multiplication(*) operators:

```
float mult(float a, float b)
{
    float m;

    _asm
    {
        fld a
        fld b
        fmul
        fstp m
    }

    return m;
}

float div(float numerator, float denominator)
{
    float d;

    _asm
    {
        fld numerator
        fld denominator
        fdiv
        fstp d
    }

    return d;
}
```

Since nobody provided solution here is multiplication (normalized only):

```
float mul(float a, float b)
{
    // for normalized floats only

    unsigned int a_bits = *((unsigned int*)&a);
    unsigned int b_bits = *((unsigned int*)&b);

    // hints (* means 'any value')
    // ------------------------------------
    // sign | exp_bits | coeff_bits | value
    // ------------------------------------
    //   0  |    0     |     0      | +0.0
    //   1  |    0     |     0      | -0.0
    // ------------------------------------
    //   *  |    0     |    !0      | we'll not handle denormalized here
    //   *  |0x01-0xFE |     *      | (-1)^s * 1.coeff * 2^(exp_val-127)
    // ------------------------------------
    //   0  |   0xFF   |     0      | +Inf  0x7F800000
    //   1  |   0xFF   |     0      | -Inf  0xFF800000
    // ------------------------------------
    //   *  |   0xFF   |    !0      | NaN  for example 0x7FFFFFFF (8388607 NaN representations)
    // ------------------------------------

    // if bits 0..30 are 0 (ie. both exp and coeff bits are all 0)
    // then our number is zero and multiplication result is zero
    if ( ((a_bits << 1) == 0) || ((b_bits << 1) == 0)) // << 1 clears sign bit
    {
        return 0.0;
    }

    int a_exp_bits = (a_bits >> 23) & 0xFF;
    int b_exp_bits = (b_bits >> 23) & 0xFF;

    // when exp bits are 0xFF = value may be +-Inf or Nan so result is NaN too
    if ( (a_exp_bits == 0xF) || (b_exp_bits == 0xF))
    {
        unsigned int NaN = ~(1 << 31); // this is one of 8388607 NaN representations
        return *((float*)&NaN);
    }

    int a_exp_val = a_exp_bits - 127;
    int b_exp_val = b_exp_bits - 127;

    int a_coeff_bits = a_bits & ((1 << 24) - 1);
    int b_coeff_bits = b_bits & ((1 << 24) - 1);

    // let's multiply
    unsigned long long a24 = (unsigned long long)a_coeff_bits | (1LL << 23); // add implicit 24th bit
    unsigned long long b24 = (unsigned long long)b_coeff_bits | (1LL << 23); // add implicit 24th bit

    unsigned long long c = 0;

    // perform regular multiplication
    for(int bit = 0; bit < 24; bit++)
    {
        if (a24 & (1LL<<bit))
        {
            c += b24 << bit;
        }
    }

    // result can be 47 or 48 bit wide ie (and have 46th or 47th bit set)
    // shift coefficient/significand to the right place
    if (c & (1LL << 47))
    {
        c >>= 47 - 23;
    }
    else if (c & (1LL << 46))
    {
        c >>= 46 - 23;
    }

    c &= ~(1<<23); // clear 24th bit (implicitly stored)

    int c_exp_val = a_exp_val + b_exp_val + 1;
    if ((c_exp_val >= 0xff) || (c_exp_val <= 0))
    {
        // ble - NaN?
    }

    int c_exp_bits = ((c_exp_val + 127) & 0xFF) << 23;
    int c_sign_bit = (a_bits & (1<<31)) ^ ((b_bits & (1<<31)));

    int ret = c_sign_bit | c_exp_bits | (int)c; 

    return *((float*)&ret);
}
```

Not perfect but seems to do the job.

Comment: liked your first solution :)